# I cannot open source file clang64.exe and a crtdbg.h Error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, visual-studio-2022

Build started...

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication6, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>clang64.exe
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\msys64\clang64.exe': No such file or directory
1>ConsoleApplication6.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\yvals.h(12,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory
1>Generating Code...`enter code here`
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication6.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Is there a way to not call on msys64? I've already set up all the Windows SDK files, so I don't know what else I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This looks like a MSVC project trying to build the clang compiler as a source file. For MSBuild, you use PlatformToolset ``clang-cl`` instead of ``v143``.

Answer (score 0):

I often get this error when I forget to close the executable. Check if it's open. If not, look in the Task Manager. That fixed it when I had this problem